# SQL Server 2008 R2 STcontains spatial join using two tables

Tags: sql-server, join, geometry

I've been stabbing at this for a while and am getting nowhere, so I'm hoping that someone with greater skills than I might have the answer.

I have two tables and in one is a set of latitude and longitude coordinates as separate columns.  In the second able I have polygon shapes set in to a spatial geometry column.

The goal is to select all of the latitude and longitude pairs from table 1, which might be called separately as:

SQLSTRING = "SELECT LAT,LONG FROM dbo.Table1;"

The second table can be called using a scripting language loop to parse through each result one by one by using the following query:

SQLSTRING = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Table2 a WHERE a.POLY.STContains(geometry::STPointFromText('POINT(" & -Text Longitude Value from Table 1- & " " & -Text Latitude Value from Table 1- & ")',0))=1;"

So, my dilemma is that it surely would be possible to select all items from Table 1 and run them through a query that will only return those results where the latitude and longitude from table 1 are contained within any specified polygon stored in table 2.  The scripting language loop is so obviously inefficient, so a single SQL query that could replace this and just return any matches would be a major time and resource saver.

Any help or pointers would be most gratefully appreciated.  Thank you, in advance, for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with spatial data, you can do a cross join (join all the rows from both tables together), then filter out what matches.

```
SELECT  *
FROM   dbo.Table2 AS a
       , dbo.Table1 AS b
WHERE  a.POLY.STContains(geometry::STPointFromText('POINT('+CAST(b.LONG AS VARCHAR)+' '+CAST(b.LAT AS VARCHAR)+')',0))=1;
```

One problem with performance here is that it will need to generate the geometry object repeatedly. It would be better if you could create a column to hold the geometry for table1. Make sure you have an spatial index on POLY in Table2 also.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply and this looks so much simpler than the nightmarishly long SQL string that I was trying (and failing) with.

I tried your example, but it's throwing an equally long error and it has to do with where the b.LONG and b.LAT are being passed to the STContains.

Here's what I'm trying:

`SELECT  *
FROM dbo.ShapeGeometryTable AS a, 
dbo.LatLongPairTable AS b 
WHERE a.POLY.STContains(geometry::STPointFromText('POINT(b.LONG b.LAT)',0))=1;`

Your thoughts on where I'm dropping the ball on the fundamentals with this?  Thanks again, and for the index suggestion!

Comment: Can you paste some (preferably all) of the error message? To create the geometry point, you need to pass in the columns like this:`SELECT * FROM dbo.ShapeGeometryTable AS a, dbo.LatLongPairTable AS b WHERE a.POLY.STContains(geometry::STPointFromText('POINT('+b.LONG+' '+b.LAT'+)',0))=1;`

Comment: Terry, you asked about the fundamentals on what's going on. You need to start by making sure you're the syntax is right for making the geometry object. Once you're able to create the geometry object, use that same SQL as the parameter for your STContains. Try the following: `SELECT geometry::STPointFromText('POINT('+LONG+' '+LAT'+)',0) FROM dbo.LatLongPairTable`

Comment: Using your latest example of:

`a.POLY.STContains(geometry::STPointFromText('POINT('+b.LONG+' '+b.LAT+')',0))=1`

I'm now getting this error - Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e07' [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Error converting data type varchar to float.

The previous error was too long to fit in to the space allotted in to this reply, but it seems that we're getting closer since this error is about 1/20th the length.  =)  Thanks again!

Comment: Great, sounds good. The previous error was from trying to convert the text "b.LONG b.LAT" into coordinates. The current error is because you're trying to mix text and numbers without telling SQL which way to convert. Try the following: `a.POLY.STContains(geometry::STPointFromText('POINT('+CAST(b.LONG AS VARCHAR)+' '+CAST(b.LAT AS VARCHAR)+')',0))=1`

Comment: Dan, you are a god amongst men, truly.  My primary issue is that I had made this seemly simple problem so overly complex that I had built it in to something that seemed overwhelming, and you cut cut through that and provided a simple and elegant example.  Thank you very much for your help and it's working perfectly.

Comment: I'm glad it's working. I've updated my original reply in case someone comes through looking for the same question.